# Non adjacent form of an integer is unique

Tags: elliptic-curves, number-theory

I have tried to look up the proof for NAF (Non-adjacent form) being unique for every integer, but as far as I have seen, textbooks only mention it as a property of NAF, but no proof is given. Also I understand that the number of zeroes in NAF representation is more than in its binary representation but how do I prove that NAF representation of an integer has 2k/3 zeroes for a k-bit integer in general. Even a textbook reference that contains these proofs would be appreciated.

Comment: I have looked at Stinson and a couple of other textbooks, but I couldn't find these proofs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Non-Adjacent Form (NAF), also called Balanced Binary Representation (BBR), is a representation of integers reminiscent of binary, but with an extra $-1$ value for digits, and such that at least one of two adjacent digits is $0$. Because the resulting representation has at least half of its digits at zero (typically about $2/3$), it can be used to speed-up modular exponentiation, or point multiplication on an arbitrary group (e.g. Elliptic Curve).

---

We define a NAF of $a\in\mathbb N$ as any [tuple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) of $j\in\mathbb N$ integers $a_i\in\{-1,0,+1\}$ with $0\le i<j$, such that:

- $a=\sum_{i=0}^{i=j-1}a_j\;2^j\;\;$ (same formula as for binary)
- $j>0\implies a_{j-1}\ne0\;\;$ (the highest-rank digit, if any, is non-zero)
- $0<i<j\implies a_i\;a_{i-1}=0\;\;$ (at least one of two adjacent digits is $0$)

Each $a$ has a unique NAF (we'll prove this in detail). These defining properties of NAF need no change for an extension to $a\in\mathbb Z$. There is either $0$ or $1$ more digit in the NAF for $a$ than in the binary representation of $|a|$; more precisely, for $a\ne0$, $j=\lceil\log_2(3|a|)\rceil-1$.

Counting from $0$ in NAF goes (showing the big-endian form, then the little-endian tuple):
 $\;a=0:\;$             $\;\;\;j=0\;\;()$
 $\;a=1:\;$          `+1` $\;\;\;j=1\;\;(a_0=+1)$
 $\;a=2:\;$       `+1  0` $\;\;\;j=2\;\;(a_0=\;\;\;0,\;a_1=+1)$
 $\;a=3:\;$    `+1  0 -1` $\;\;\;j=3\;\;(a_0=-1,\;a_1=\;\;\;0,\;a_2=+1)$
 $\;a=4:\;$    `+1  0  0` $\;\;\;j=3\;\;(a_0=\;\;\;0,\;a_1=\;\;\;0,\;a_2=+1)$
 $\;a=5:\;$    `+1  0 +1` $\;\;\;j=3\;\;(a_0=+1,\;a_1=\;\;\;0,\;a_2=+1)$
 $\;a=6:\;$ `+1  0 -1  0` $\;\;\;j=4\;\;(a_0=\;\;\;0,\;a_1=-1,\;a_2=\;\;\;0,\;a_3=+1)$
 $\;a=7:\;$ `+1  0  0 -1` $\;\;\;j=4\;\;(a_0=-1,\;a_1=\;\;\;0,\;a_2=\;\;\;0,\;a_3=+1)$
 $\;a=8:\;$ `+1  0  0  0` $\;\;\;j=4\;\;(a_0=\;\;\;0,\;a_1=\;\;\;0,\;a_2=\;\;\;0,\;a_3=+1)$
 $\;a=9:\;$ `+1  0  0 +1` $\;\;\;j=4\;\;(a_0=+1,\;a_1=\;\;\;0,\;a_2=\;\;\;0,\;a_3=+1)$

---

To establish that an integer $a$ can't have two different NAFs, we use an argument of [infinite descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent), a special case of proof by contradiction. We hypothesize there exists integer(s) with at least two distinct NAFs, and define $a$ as the smallest such integer. We'll construct an integer $b$ less than $a$ with two distinct NAFs (leading to contradiction).

We note one of the two distinct NAFs for $a$ using $j$ and $a_i$, and another using $\tilde j$ and $\tilde a_i$, swapping theses if necessary so that $\tilde j\le j$. The only case with $j=0$ gives both NAF empty, thus identical, hence $j\ge1$.

If we had $a=0$, we would have $a=0=\sum_{i=0}^{i=j-1}a_j\;2^j$ with $a_{j-1}\ne0$, and by explicitly computing the minimum and maximum of the other terms as a [sum-of-powers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_powers), we show this can't hold. Hence $a>0$, and hence $\tilde j\ge1$.

We consider three cases each leading to contradiction:

- If $a\equiv0\pmod2$, then by reducing modulo $2$ the equation $a=\sum a_i\;2^i$, it comes that $a_0=0$.
  $b=a/2$ is an integer less than $a$ (since $2b=a$ with $a>0$), and it's easily verified that the $j-1$ integers $b_i=a_{i+1}$ for $0\le i<j-1$ obey each condition for a NAF for that $b$. Similarly, a NAF for that $b$ is the $\tilde j-1$ integers $\tilde b_i=\tilde a_{i+1}$ for $0\le i<\tilde j-1$, and that's another NAF (since $a_0=0=\tilde a_0$ and the two NAFs for $a$ are distinct).
- If $a\equiv1\pmod4$, then by reducing modulo $4$ the equation $a=\sum a_i\;2^i$, it comes that $2a_1+a_0\equiv1\pmod4$, thus $a_1=0$ and $a_0=+1$ (notice that $a_1=+1$ and $a_0=-1$ is ruled out by $a_1\;a_0=0$).
  $b=a-1$ is an integer less than $a$, and a NAF for that $b$ is the $j$ integers $b_0=0$, and $b_i=a_i$ for $1\le i<j$. Similarly, another NAF for that $b$ is the $\tilde j$ integers $\tilde b_0=0$, and $\tilde b_i=\tilde a_i$ for $1\le i<\tilde j$.
- If $a\equiv3\pmod4$, then by reducing modulo $4$ the equation $a=\sum a_i\;2^i$, it comes that $2a_1+a_0\equiv3\pmod4$, thus $a_1=0$ and $a_0=-1$ (notice that $a_1=-1$ and $a_0=+1$ is ruled out by $a_1\;a_0=0$).
  $b=(a+1)/2$ is an integer less than $a$, and a NAF for that $b$ is the $j-1$ integers $b_i=a_{i+1}$ for $0\le i<j-1$. Similarly, another NAF for that $b$ is the $\tilde j-1$ integers $\tilde b_i=\tilde a_{i+1}$ for $0\le i<\tilde j-1$.

---

There are several ways to explicitly construct the NAF of an arbitrary integer $a>0$ from that of a smaller integer $b$, recursively, until reaching $b=0$ that has a trivial NAF. For example:

- If $a\equiv0\pmod2$, we build the NAF for $a$ as a tuple with one more element than the NAF of $b=a/2$, with $a_0=0$, $a_{i+1}=b_i$.
- If $a\equiv1\pmod4$, we build the NAF for $a$ as a tuple with two more elements than the NAF of $b=(a-1)/4$, with $a_0=+1$, $a_1=0$, $a_{i+2}=b_i$.
- If $a\equiv3\pmod4$, we build the NAF for $a$ as a tuple with two more elements than the NAF of $b=(a+1)/4$, with $a_0=-1$, $a_1=0$, $a_{i+2}=b_i$.

In all three case, it is easy to derive the properties required from the NAF of $a$ from these for the NAF of $b$.

---

Various sources credit the idea, proof of uniqueness of NAF representation, and proof of optimality of the non-adjacency criteria from the standpoint of maximizing the number of zeros, to
George W. Reitwiesner, [*Binary arithmetic*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0065245808606105) (paywalled), Advances in Computers, vol. 1, pp. 231-308, 1960.

I recommend Jeffrey Shallit: [*A Primer on Balanced Binary Representations*](http://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Papers/bbr.pdf) (1992-1993, Department of Computer Science, University of Waterloo). <sub><sup>I'm not the only [one to find it late](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/a8/a8.pdf)!</sup></sub>

Marc Joye and Christophe Tymen: [*Compact Encoding of Non-Adjacent Forms with Applications to Elliptic Curve Cryptography*](http://www.liafa.jussieu.fr/~cf/M2/joye.pdf) (in [proceedings of Public Key Cryptography 2001](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-44586-2_26)) notice that we can re-encode NAF as bits using a simple Hamming code, storing integers as NAF essentially as compactly as in binary, while keeping them directly usable for fast point multiplication.

Comment: So we prove this by contradiction. We assume 'a' to be the smallest integer with two distinct naf's and arrive at a smaller integer that has to have distinct naf's. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Also, for the second case, I don't understand why (a-1)/4 has two distinct NAFs instead of (n-1)/2. It might seem like a trivial question, but bear with me, I am still learning.

Comment: @Vi Jay: Yes, your summary is correct. The answer now gives more details on the general method, called _infinite descent_ , a special form of proof by contradiction. $\;$ Also I revised the proof. Formerly I used $b=(a−1)/4$ in the second case of the second proof, in order to match the first proof, but that left a gap because I assumed without proof that small $a$ had a single NAF. Now I'm first proving that $0$ has a single NAF, and in the second case of the second proof use $b=a−1$, which is simplest. $b=(a−1)/2$ also works.

Comment: Thanks for that elaborate proof. Do you happen to know a textbook that goes into such details about NAF, not just stating its properties but explaining why they are so.